# JSON to POJO and vise-versa for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, restlet

My applications use common *Models* integrated as dependencies for multiple application. One of the app the has a dependency on the *Models* have a Restlet connection through Restlet:

```
ClientResource res = new ClientResource("/path");
            res.setOnResponse(new Uniform() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                    try {
                        if(!response.getStatus().isError()){
                           String body = response.getEntity().getText();
                          // do stuff with Response JSON
                        } else {

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                       // handle error
                    }
                }
            });
res.post(new JsonRepresentation(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, jsonObject));
```

I have two questions for this,

1. Is there a straightforward way for marshalling a POJO into a `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject` in GWT for use with the `res.post` above
2. Is there a straightforward way for marshalling a JSON String into a POJO with GWT?

That is both applicable in the `ClientResource` above as well as not resort into using GWT Overlay types as we already a Model shared in both client and server-side. Something that is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean / JSON conversion isn't supported by Restlet out of the box. If you want to use beans within Restlet, you should use the native GWT protocol. It's the guidance that chose Restlet for its GWT implementation. You could have the content types enabled within Restlet and select the one you want with the content negotiation (GWT RPC for GWT clients and JSON for others).

That said, I understand your approach. Restlet leverages the generator feature to directly work on beans in the case of the GWT RPC (see this class https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/rebind/ClientProxyGenerator.java.gwt). The generator only support the media type for GWT RPC but could be extended to handle other media types like JSON. Notice that such approach is tricker that the one provided by [Ümit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356594/%C3%9Cmit) in its answer.

Hope it give you some hints to fix your problem,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK there is no automated and easy way to convert a POJO into `JSONObject`s. Most likely you would have to do it by hand. The `JsonRepresentation` constructor however accepts a JSON String, so you could use on of the alternatives (see point 2)
2. There are a couple of alternative easier ways to convert POJOs to JSON:

   - [AutoBeans](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html)
   - [Piriti](https://github.com/hpehl/piriti)
   - [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding)

I guess if you have common POJO's the easiest solution would be to use `AutoBeans`. You would define an interface with all the setters and getters for each POJO and have the POJO's implement those interfaces.